# Number of ways to fold a 2x4 map

Tags: mathematics, topology

M.Gardner in his book "Mathematical puzzles and diversions" states that the following 2x4 map

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
   1 & \phantom{1} & \phantom{1} & \phantom{1} \\
\hline
   \phantom{1} & \phantom{1} & \phantom{1} & \phantom{1} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

can be folded in 40 different ways (along 7 segments shown) that the cell with 1 on it will be the upper one.

How to count all these ways and prove that there are exactly 40 of them?

Comment: It's only 40. Just count them. Be systematic about the order. Horizontal and vertical folds are embarrassingly separable, and there's a tiny number of vertical folding regimes that don't leave cell 1 exposed.

Comment: @gregm, that is not so easy. Try it.

Comment: @kaine, 1 is on one side. The result should be 1x1 "map". Would you mind to show your 20 ways in an answer? I will try to find as many as I can in nearest future too.

Comment: @kaine, do you take into account folds like $$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
   1 & 8 & 2 & 6 \\
\hline
   4 & 7 & 3 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$? here numbers are positions of the cells in the folded "map".

Comment: Yes. this is one of the 4 "pocket" ones.  This is the one where you fold the horizontal first and the right vertical "down".  There are also 3 where you fold the right one the other way or you fold the horizontal after folding the right one.

Comment: @kaine, i think you are wrong that vertical folding order doesn't matter, it matters if you put horizontal in-between.

Comment: @klm123 I am tempted to put a bounty on this question but do not want to do so if you already have an answer.  Do you know what the last one is? Is my partial answer clearer now?

Comment: @JoeZ., i guess no. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For short hand: the horizontal line is $H$, the center vertical is $C$, the one to the left of $C$ is $L$, and the one to the right of $C$ is $R$. The cells are:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
   8 & 7 & 6 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{array}

### Fold $H$ last: 4 ways

$H$ and $L$ have 1 way to fold, so here can be ignored. As $C$ and $R$ have 2 ways to fold and their order doesn't matter (make dulplicate orientations) there are only $2\times2=4$ different ways to fold the sheet ignoring $H$ for the end.

### Fold $H$ first: 7 ways

If one were to fold $H$ first, there are 6 different ways to fold the sheet. 4 are simply folding $R$ and $C$ in their 2 possible ways.  The other 2 involve tucking cells $3-6$ between $1$ and $8$.

The seventh was well decribed by klm123 and aschepler: Fold $Ho$ . Slide $4-5$  between $1,8$. Making it more like a cylinder than a triangle, continue sliding in until $4-5$  are between $2,7$  and $3,6$  are between $1,8$. Then you can fully flatten the LoCoRo  creases, making it a 1x1 square.

### Fold $R$ then $H$ first: 6 ways

If one folds $R$ then $H$ one gets 6 orientations in exactly the same way as the first 6 option from folding $H$ first.

### Fold $R$ and $C$ then $H$ first: + 4 ways

Neither $H$ last nor $L$ last scenereos can cover square $1$ as long as $H$ and $L$ are both folded out and no tucking possible as the first two folds quickly shorten the paper.  This means that there are 8 possibilitys: $RoCoHoLo,RiCoHoLo,RoCiHoLo,RiCiHoLo$ and the same ones with $LoHo$ (but these 4 are duplicates of $H$ last).

### Fold $R$ and $L$ then $H$ first: see below (Fold $L$ and $R$ then $H$ then $C$)

### Fold $C$ then $H$ first: 3 ways

$C$ can now only be folded "out" in the same direction as $H$ or cell $1$ is covered.
Once this is done, however, $R$ can be folded into three different orientations.  The options are to place $4$ and $5$ between $1$ and $8$,$2$ and $3$ or $7$ and $6$.  Folding $L$ makes it a 1x1 but doesn't change the number of patterns.

### Fold $C$ and $L$ then $H$ first: 3 ways

$C$ can now only be folded "in" and $L$ must be folded "out".
Similar to the previous case, there are 3 different options based on folding $R$ after $H$.  They are to place to place $4$ and $5$ at the bottom, between $6$ and $7$ or between $2$ and $3$.

### Fold $C$ and $R$ then $H$ first: see above (Fold $R$ and $C$ then $H$ first)

### Fold $L$ then $H$ first: 7 ways

$L$ can now only be folded "out" and $H$ must be folded "out".
This yields 7 different possibilities based on where $3-6$ are placed.  There is: one with $4-5$ between $2$ and $7$; 2 ($Ri$ and $Ro$) with $3-6$ between $1$ and $2$; 2 with $3-6$ between $7$ and $8$; and 2 with $3-6$ on the bottom.

### Fold $L$ and $R$ then $H$ then $C$: 6 ways

$L$ can now only be folded "out".
This yields 6 different possibilities based on where $3-6$ are placed.  There are: 2 ($Ri$ and $Ro$) with $3-6$ between $1$ and $2$; 2 with $3-6$ between $7$ and $8$; and 2 with $3-6$ on the bottom.

Comment: Case "Fold R then H first." I see only 4 here. How do you do it in the same way as Hfirst?

Comment: (R out, H out, C out, L out) (R out, H out, C in, L out) (R in, H out, C out, L out) (R in, H out, C in, L out) (R out, H out, C out, L out, tuck 3-6 betweeen 1 and 8) (R in, H out, C out, L out, tuck 3-6 betweeen 1 and 8)

Comment: Thanks. I get it. But the other 2 chapters is even harder to understand...

Comment: I think "\\$" is no longer used. You must use $ only.

Comment: +1. Great answer. I hope you don;t mind that I added a little bit more structure to be sure nothing is missing. I think you hve missed one tucking fold in "Fold H first", see number 5 in my answer (I missed one of yours there too...).

Comment: Aha, yes, that's the last one.  Another way to describe klm's number 5 using kaine's notation: Fold $Ho$. Slide $4,5$ between $1,8$. Making it more like a cylinder than a triangle, continue sliding in until $4,5$ are between $2,7$ and $3,6$ are between $1,8$. Then you can fully flatten the $LoCoRo$ creases, making it a 1x1 square.

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed that one completely! The quesiton is finally answered fully in an easiler found place online!

Comment: It is interesting that you can group ways by 10: 40=2*(6+4)+2*(7+3).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer, but just one step forward it.
I give here 29 ways to fold the map + idea for 4 more ways.

I number the cells according to positions they would take at the resulting 1x1 folder map, counting from top to bottom.

Notations: H - fold along horizontal line; VI - fold along I-th vertical line; in - fold in a way that front part (usually with numbers) will be hidden inside; out - fold in a way that front part (usually with numbers) will be outside; "IJ" - cell in I-th row and J-th column.

**Left-to-right order of vertical folds.**

6 when fold horizontal first:

1. Hout, V1out, V2in, V3out
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 4 & 5 & 7 \\
   \hline
      2 & 3 & 6 & 8 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
2. Hout, Vout, Vin, Vin
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 4 & 7 & 6 \\
   \hline
      2 & 3 & 8 & 5 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
3. Hout, V1out, V2out, V3in
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 5 & 4 \\
   \hline
      2 & 7 & 6 & 3 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
4. Hout, V1out, V2out, V3out
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 3 & 6 \\
   \hline
      2 & 7 & 4 & 5 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
5. Hout, V1out, V2out, V3out (right end should go inside of left end)
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 2 & 7 \\
   \hline
      4 & 5 & 3 & 6 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
6. Hout, V1out, V2out, V3out (folded half right end should go in-front of "21")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 2 & 5 \\
   \hline
      6 & 7 & 3 & 4 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$

6 when fold horizontal 2-nd:

1. V1out, Hout, V2in, V3out (folded half must be put behind "1")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 6 & 5 & 2 \\
   \hline
      8 & 7 & 4 & 3 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
2. V1out, Hout, V2in, V3in (folded half must be put behind "11")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 6 & 3 & 4 \\
   \hline
      8 & 7 & 2 & 5 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
3. V1out, Hout, V2out, V3in
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 2 & 6 & 7 \\
   \hline
      4 & 3 & 5 & 8 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
4. V1out, Hout, V2out, V3in (folded half must be put in-front of "21")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 2 & 5 & 6 \\
   \hline
      8 & 3 & 4 & 7 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
5. V1out, Hout, V2out, V3out
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 2 & 8 & 5 \\
   \hline
      4 & 3 & 7 & 6 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
6. V1out, Hout, V2out, V3out (folded half must be put in-front of "21")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 2 & 7 & 4 \\
   \hline
      7 & 3 & 6 & 5 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$

4 when fold horizontal 3-rd:

1. V1out, V2in, Hout, V3out
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 6 & 3 & 8 \\
   \hline
      8 & 5 & 4 & 7 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
2. V1out, V2in, Hout, V3out (folded half must be put in-front of "21" and "22")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 6 & 3 & 8 \\
   \hline
      8 & 5 & 4 & 7 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
3. V1out, V2in, Hout, V3in (folded half must be put behind of "11" and "12")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 2 & 5 & 4 \\
   \hline
      8 & 7 & 6 & 3 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
4. V1out, V2out, Hout, V3in (impossible)
5. V1out, V2out, Hout, V3out (impossible)

4 when fold horizontal 4-th:

1. V1out, V2in, V3out, Hout
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
   \hline
      8 & 7 & 6 & 5 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
2. Vout, Vin, Vin, Hout 
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
   \hline
      8 & 7 & 5 & 6 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
3. V1out, V2out, V3in, Hout
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
   \hline
      8 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
4. V1out, V2out, V3out, Hout
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
   \hline
      8 & 5 & 7 & 6 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$

**V2 first.**

3 when fold horizontal 2-nd:

1. V2out, Hout, V1out, V3out
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 7 & 2 \\
   \hline
      4 & 5 & 6 & 3 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
2. V2out, Hout, V1out, V3out ("14" goes behind "22")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 7 & 4 \\
   \hline
      2 & 3 & 6 & 5 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
3. V2out, Hout, V1out, V3in ("14" goes behind "13")
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 5 & 7 \\
   \hline
      2 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$

6 when fold horizontal 3-nd:

1. V2out, V1***, Hout (is impossible)
2. V2out, V3out, Hout, V1in
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 6 & 7 \\
   \hline
      2 & 3 & 5 & 4 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
3. V2out, V3in, Hout, V1in
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 7 & 6 \\
   \hline
      2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
4. V2in, V1out, Hout, V1in ("14" in-front "13)
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 5 & 4 \\
   \hline
      2 & 7 & 6 & 3 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
5. V2in, V1out, Hout, V1out ("14" behind "13)
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 8 & 3 & 6 \\
   \hline
      2 & 7 & 4 & 5 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
6. V2out, V3out, Hout, V1in
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
   \hline
      2 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$
7. V2out, V3in, Hout, V1in
   $$
   \begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
      1 & 6 & 8 & 7 \\
   \hline
      2 & 5 & 3 & 4 \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   $$

**V3 first. H 2-nd**

1. V3in, Hout, V1out, V2out
2. V3in, Hout, V1out, V2in
3. V3out, Hout, V1out, V2out
4. V3out, Hout, V1out, V2in

(to be continued)